# JavaScript Split Regular Expression keep the delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript I'm trying to split a paragraph into it's sentences using regular expressions.  My regular expression doesn't account for a sentence being inside brackets and  I would like to keep the delimiter.

I've put an example of the code in jsFiddle.net [here](http://jsfiddle.net/swaBw/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the match approach rather than split. It could be tighter (e.g. what if a sentence ends with `...`, etc).

```
text.match(/\(?[A-Z][^\.]+[\.!\?]\)?(\s+|$)/g);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DepKF/1/

Comment: You pretty much have to use `match`, since JS doesn't have a delimiter-capture option for `split`.

Comment: Yes you can use split. But you need a look-ahead (that an no capturing group) 
`text.split(/\b(?![\?\.\!])/);`

Answer (score 1):

@Utkanos You idea is good, but I think `replace` may better:

```
text.replace(/\(?[A-Z][^\.]+[\.!\?]\)?/g, function (sentence) {
    output += '<p>'+ sentence + '</p>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juGT7/1/

You no need to loop again.

Comment: I hadn't thought if going down this route.  Really good thanks but I need the loop for other things later on.

Comment: @wiky - I did give this method some thought, but ultimately there's no computational saving because there is a loop nonetheless - in this case, the loop is the iterative callback.

Answer (score 1):

use the (?=pattern) lookahead pattern in the regex
example

```
var string = '500x500-11*90~1+1';
string = string.replace(/(?=[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]])/gi, ",");
string = string.split(",");
```

this will give you the following result.

```
[ '500x500', '-11', '*90', '~1', '+1' ]
```

Can also be directly split

```
string = string.split(/(?=[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]])/gi);
```

giving the same result

```
[ '500x500', '-11', '*90', '~1', '+1' ]
```