# Javascript RegExp for splitting text into sentences and keeping the delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, sentence

I am trying to use javascript's split to get the sentences out of a string but keep the delimiter eg !?.

So far I have

```
sentences = text.split(/[\\.!?]/);
```

which works but does not include the ending punctuation for each sentence (.!?).

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: `?` is also a special char in RegExp so you need to escape it

Comment: Metacharacters like `.` and `?` lose their special meanings inside a character class.  The correct way to match a dot (`.`), an exclamation point (`!`), or a question mark (`?`) is `[.!?]`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to use match not split.

Try this.

```
var str = "I like turtles. Do you? Awesome! hahaha. lol!!! What's going on????";
var result = str.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );

var expect = ["I like turtles.", " Do you?", " Awesome!", " hahaha.", " lol!!!", " What's going on????"];
console.log( result.join(" ") === expect.join(" ") )
console.log( result.length === 6);
```

Comment: You can use a split:
`text.split(/\b(?![\?\.\!])/);`
\b tells it to split on word boundaries, the nifty part is the negative look-ahead.

Comment: The regex is wrong. If I type: "Phrase 1. Phrase 2. Phrase 3", "Phrase 3" gets thrown away.

Comment: Here's a variation that also works when the last sentence ends without punctuation:
`var result = str.match(/([^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+)|([^\.!\?]+$)/g);`

Comment: Wow, this stuff also catches ellipsis too. `var str = "I like turtles... Do you? Awesome! hahaha. lol!!! What's going on????";
`

Comment: this breaks when having floating point numbers: `Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"`

Comment: It picks abbreviations such as P.S. and makes it P. S. Any clue how to manage abbreviations?

Answer (score 12):

The following is a small addition to Larry's answer which will match also paranthetical sentences:

```
text.match(/\(?[^\.\?\!]+[\.!\?]\)?/g);
```

applied on:

```
text = "If he's restin', I'll wake him up! (Shouts at the cage.) 
'Ello, Mister Polly Parrot! (Owner hits the cage.) There, he moved!!!"
```

giveth:

```
["If he's restin', I'll wake him up!", " (Shouts at the cage.)", 
" 'Ello, Mister Polly Parrot!", " (Owner hits the cage.)", " There, he moved!!!"]
```

Comment: You missed the `+` after the punctuation character class `[.!?]`, so it will not capture the three exclamations after "he moved".

Answer (score 9):

Improving on lonemc's answer (which improved on Mia Chen's answer, which improved on mircealungu's answer):

First, we can stick a `u` option at the end in order to match unicode characters. In other words, we probably want to be able to parse German sentences, French sentences, etc.

Second, instead of hard-coding the characters that should end a sentence, we can use "Sentence_Terminal", which [is part of the unicode standard](http://unicode.org/L2/L2003/03145-sentence-term.htm).

Third, instead of hard-coding the characters that make up a closing bracket, we can use "[Close_Punctuation](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pe/list.htm)".

Forth, instead of hard-coding the characters that make up a closing quote, we can use "[Final_Punctuation](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pf/list.htm)".

Fifth, we might not want to match things that look like enums. For example:

> This is the first sentence! This is the second sentence with MyEnum.Value1 where I talk about it!

In order to do that, we can compose a match using a lookahead pattern:

```
string.match(/(?=[^])(?:\P{Sentence_Terminal}|\p{Sentence_Terminal}(?!['"`\p{Close_Punctuation}\p{Final_Punctuation}\s]))*(?:\p{Sentence_Terminal}+['"`\p{Close_Punctuation}\p{Final_Punctuation}]*|$)/guy);
```

Here's a link to the regex on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Awcj1k/1).

Comment: This is a great regex, just has one flaw: it will match quoted sentences like `He said "This is a pen. I like it".` into two separate sentences. I think quoted sentences should be treated as a part of it's "parent" sentence. So far I couldn't modify this regex to fix this issue. Any chance you know how to do it?

Comment: Note that your quote is not valid English grammar. It would be correctly written as: `He said, "This is a pen. I like it."` With that said, the regex will still parse it as two separate sentences, but that is not a bug. This is given away by the grammatically correct placement of the punctuation. In other words, we consider the "He said" as part of the first sentence. But when the person inside the quote terminates a sentence, so does the speaker outside of the sentence. Google around for some grammar guides on quoting (I don't know of any good ones to recommend offhand).

Comment: While I agree with you on the grammar standpoint, I think from the technical side a program should treat this something like a tree of nested sentences. This is particularly useful in my application. Suppose you need to give the user a list of sentences. The output would look like this: ['He said, "This is a pen.', 'I like it".'] This isn't quite right since there are only one quotation mark in each sentence. Could you please provide a regex that would fit my case?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, since you would never want to parse that using regex. You want to parse an array like that using JSON.parse or some other data parsing method. This is a famous programming mistake, e.g. see this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:-

```
sentences = text.split(/[\\.!\?]/);
```

`?` is a special char in regular expressions so need to be escaped.

Sorry I miss read your question - if you want to keep delimiters then you need to use `match` not `split` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230178/javascript-split-regular-expression-keep-the-delimiter)

Comment: Just a small note: special characters like `?` don't need to be escaped inside a character class (the square brackets).

Answer (score 5):

Improving on Mia's answer here is a version which also includes ending sentences with no punctuation:

```
string.match(/[^.?!]+[.!?]+[\])'"`’”]*|.+/g)
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement on mircealungu's answer:

```
string.match(/[^.?!]+[.!?]+[\])'"`’”]*/g);
```

- There's no need for the opening parenthesis at the beginning.
- Punctuation like `'...'`, `'!!!'`, `'!?'` etc. are included inside sentences.
- Any number of square close brackets and close parentheses are included. [Edit: different closing quotation marks added]

Comment: Is `...?` supported?