# How can I split a body of text into both sentences and/or paragraph breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to split a body of text such as:

```
var str = "This is one.  Two because of space break
This is number three! 


And Four?!?!"
```

Using `str.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g )` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761563/javascript-regexp-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-and-keeping-the-delimiter) I get the following 3.

```
[ 'This is one.',
  '  Two because of space break\r\n    This is number three!',
  ' \r\n\r\n\r\n    And Four?!?!' ]
```

Instead I would like to have 4 different and clean (no \r\n)  values because of the page break.  I tried using `str.replace(/\r?\n/g,'.');` before the match function and that sort of works, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way maybe by combining regexes?

I would like to get:

```
['This is one.', 'Two because of space break', 'This is number three!', 'And Four?!?!']
```

Comment: If you stop using Internet Explorer, the issue solves itself !!

Comment: I'm not using IE, I'm using chrome

Comment: What's the criterion for separation of phrases? The dot, or the double space?

Comment: Any punctuation like `!?.` and a paragraph break

Comment: Chrome doesn't use `CRLF`, only `LF`, so a string created in the browser enviroment shouldn't return `\r\n` at all, but just `\n`. On the other hand, you can't have multiline strings, so it's probably coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I'm seeing \n and \r in terminal so that may explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
str.match(/[^\s.!?]+[^.!?\r\n]+[.!?]*/g);
```