# Formatting of date and time in Google Script for google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

One follow up question to another question I asked ([Parse String to get "date", "time" and "other", with Regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572036/parse-string-to-get-date-time-and-other-with-regexp)): I now have a date in the format dd.mm.yyyy and a start time and end time (on the European 24h scale) as variables in my Google Script. What I ultimately want to do is have an event with these dates in my google calendar. I know how to create an event, but how can I format my date & time variables to make this work? I don't know if it's relevant, but I live in the Central European time zone.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best, Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the separate values (hours, minutes and dates) it becomes quite easy to build date objects with these values.

Calendar events need 2 full date object, one for start date/time and one for end date/time.

The code might be written in different ways, below is an example that proceeds step by step to help you  better seeing what happens.

```
function myFunction() {
  var timeString = 'Event in Cologne 25.10.2014 18:30 - 23:00';// your data looks like this
  var date = timeString.match(/([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)/g).toString().split('.');// decompose in an array of dd,mm,yyyy
  var time = timeString.match(/((([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):)([0-5][0-9])/g);// this is start and end time
  Logger.log('date='+date+'  time='+time);// check the values in logger
  var start = new Date(date[2],date[1]-1,date[0]);//create date object for start
  start.setHours(time[0].split(':')[0]);//set hours
  start.setMinutes(time[0].split(':')[1]);//set minutes
  var end = new Date(date[2],date[1]-1,date[0]);//same for end
  end.setHours(time[1].split(':')[0]);
  end.setMinutes(time[1].split(':')[1]);
  Logger.log('\nstart = '+start+'\nend = '+end);// check final result
}
```

Log result :

[image]