# How to show parts of a string in a ordered list

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an String:

```
var data = 'Hei, how are u?. I am good. And you?.'
```

I am using EJS as my view engine, and i want show like this:

1. Hei, how are u?.
2. I am good.
3. And you?.

Currently i am using an array of arrays:

```
var data = [
  ['Hei, how are u?'],
  ['I am good.'],
  ['And you?']
]
```

Them i can do a for loop and show like a list.

This was the only way I could do, but I believe I'm doing wrong.

Can someone give me a hand here?

How break the string and show like a list in the HTML?

Comment: won't array of strings do instead of array of arrays? `var data = [
  'Hei, how are u?',
  'I am good.',
  'And you?'
]`

Comment: but how show like a list in the html using arrays of strings?

Comment: You should use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to separate the original string. A possible separator might be `"."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say this is the data passed to ejs template.

```
var data = { parts: [ 'Hei, how are u?', 'I am good.', 'And you?' ] };
```

in ejs template:

```
<ol>
<% for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= parts[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ol>
```

note: use regex to split string into parts matching '.', '?' etc.

```
var txt = 'Hei, how are u?. I am good. And you?.';
var parts = txt.match(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g);
var data = { parts: parts };
```

regex code reference: [Javascript RegExp for splitting text into sentences and keeping the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761563/javascript-regexp-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-and-keeping-the-delimiter#11761720)

Comment: i prefer not use modules if i can do without them what i want, because of this i am going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

sentence splitter can be used using

`https://github.com/parmentf/node-sentence-tokenizer`

and then use `ejs` for array parsing.

Thanks.