# Javascript RegExp for splitting text into sentences with quotes and keeping the delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, sentence

I'm trying to split a sentence with .!? like it was done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761563/javascript-regexp-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-and-keeping-the-delimiter), but also account for possible double quotes at the beginning and end of a sentence. I'm using this:

```js
let str = '" Non. Es-tu sûr ? "';
let result = str.match(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g);

console.log(result)
```

But when I do it, the 2 characters after the **?** are not caught. So instead of getting:

> ['" Non.', 'Es-tu sûr ? "']

I'm getting:

> ['" Non.', 'Es-tu sûr ?']

Is there anyway to split these sentences using regex?

Comment: What is the requirement here? If you mean to match any non-word chars, try `/[^.!?]+[.!?]+\W*/g`. It may grab a bit too much if the next sentence first letter is not an ASCII letter though. If you plan to match punctuation with spaces try `/[^.!?]+[\s.!?!-#%-*,-\/\\:;?@[-\]_{}]+/g`. You may add all Unicode punctuation here, if need be.

Comment: *I'm trying to split a sentence* - on the basis of which character? Is it period (`.`) character?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I don't control the input, so I'm still testing the possible sentence splitters. For now I'm just considering the typical ones: .!? and the double quotes.

Comment: Then use `/[^.!?]+[.!?]+[\s"]*/g`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226132/3832970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you need to do is optionally match `"`s at the beginning and end:

```js
let str = '" Non. Es-tu sûr ? "';
console.log(
  str.match( /"?[^.!?]+[.!?]+(?: *")?/g )
);
```

Comment: This is it, thanks! I was trying to consider the quotes as another sentence finisher. So I was thinking that it should end in '!' OR '.' OR '?'+ OR ' "'. But the thing was that you considered the quotes as an extra to the finisher and not a finisher.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to match additional trailing whitespace and `"` chars after final punctuation you may use

```js
let str = '" Non. Es-tu sûr ? "';
let result = str.match(/[^.!?]+[.!?]+[\s"']*/g);
console.log(result)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS7Hoc/1). The `[\s"']*` pattern matches 0 or more whitespace, `"` or `'` chars.

Note you do not need to escape `.` and `?` inside character classes.