# Splitting a string at question mark, exclamation mark, or period in javascript and retain those marks?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I was a bit surprised, that actually no one had the exact same issue in javascript...

I tried several different solutions none of them parse the content correctly.

The closest one I tried : (I stole its regex query from a PHP solution)

```
const test = `abc?aaa.abcd?.aabbccc!`;
const sentencesList = test.split("/(\?|\.|!)/");
```

But result just going to be
`["abc?aaa.abcd?.aabbccc!"]`

What I want to get is
`['abc?', 'aaa.', 'abcd?','.', 'aabbccc!']`
I am so confused.. what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Related: Javascript RegExp for splitting text into sentences and keeping the delimiter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11761563/1066234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you out, what you write is not a regex. `test.split("/(\?|\.|!)/");` is simply an 11 character string. A regex would be, for example, `test.split(/(\?|\.|!)/);`. This still would not be the regex you're looking for.

The problem with this regex is that it's looking for a `?`, `.`, or `!` character *only*, and capturing that lone character. What you want to do is find any number of characters, followed by one of those three characters.

Next, [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) does not accept regexes as arguments. You'll want to use a function that does accept them (such as [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)).

Putting this all together, you'll want to start out your regex with something like this: `/.*?/`. The dot means any character matches, the asterisk means 0 or more, and the questionmark means "non-greedy", or try to match as few characters as possible, while keeping a valid match.

To search for your three characters, you would follow this up with `/[?!.]/` to indicate you want one of these three characters (so far we have `/.*?[?!.]/`). Lastly, you want to add the g flag so it searches for every instance, rather than only the first. `/.*?[?!.]/g`. Now we can use it in `match`:

```js
const rawText = `abc?aaa.abcd?.aabbccc!`;
const matchedArray = rawText.match(/.*?[?!.]/g);
console.log(matchedArray);
```

Comment: your answer is really really detailed. I really love that! Thank you and your regex actually can run with full sentences with multiple words, which is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

`/[a-z]*[?!.]/g)` will do what you want:

```js
const test = `abc?aaa.abcd?.aabbccc!`;
console.log(test.match(/[a-z]*[?!.]/g))
```

Comment: Maybe `/[^?!.]*[?!.]/g` would be slightly more robust, but otherwise great answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts lol I was just going to mark your answer as best answer because this is a match statement instead of using in split, thank you so much for your answer (which you deleted... lol) that I realized for some reason to use @ic3b3rg answer properly I have to add `()` before and after `/../` strange... do you two know why the `()` need to be included for split?

Comment: @Ezeewei you want to use `match()` for this. `split()` is definitely not the right operation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts oh WOW! very very interesting! Did not know that's doing similar stuff.... thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, I do not think we need pattern match. I take that back, I have been answering in Java.

```
final String S = "An sentence may end with period. Does it end any other way? Ofcourse!";
final String[] simpleSentences = S.split("[?!.]");
//now simpleSentences array has three elements in it.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Comment: @Tyler2P, I added a more detailed code snippet. Does that help? And I just realised I have been answering in Java. Apologies! :D